# Flutter: Unfocus on textfield (multiline) when keyboard is dismissed via back button press

Tags: flutter

I have the following `TextFormField`:

```
TextFormField(
  focusNode: inputFocusNode, 
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  maxLines: null,
  minLines: 3,
)
```

When the textfield is on focus, the keyboard appears. When the phone back button is pressed, the keyboard disappears however the cursor on the textfield still remains.

I know you can use `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus()` to remove the cursor or unfocus. However there doesn't seem to be a direct way to detect the keyboard dismissal without getting a [package](https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_visibility#-readme-tab-)

How do I address this issue?

Comment: I'm confused bro because every time you press back button in your device it will surely dismiss device keyboard but if you want to dismiss it via clicking outside the keyboard you can use FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode()); and wrap it in GestureDetector() and set it on onTap.

Comment: or FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Like you said, when the device back button is pressed, the keyboard is dismissed for sure (like I mentioned in my question). However the cursor in the textfield is not dismissed unless I tap on something other than the textfield. I am trying to get rid of the blinking cursor when the keyboard is dismissed.

Comment: For example, I can create a `gesturedetector` with `onTap` that `unfocus` the textfield. But this relies on `tapping` something on the screen. However, when a user dismisses the keyboard via pressing the device back button, the user did not technically `tap` anything on the screen, thus does not dismisses the focus, even thought the keyboard is dismissed.

Comment: have you tried wrapping your body with WillPopScope instead of Container?

try WillPopScope(
onWillPop: ()async=> FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode()),
child: *your body*
)

Comment: or remove inputFocusNode

Comment: `WillPopScope` does not get triggered when the keyboard is active (or least that's how I understand it). 

I mean, there is a package that detects keyboard dismissal, but I am trying to avoid using packages.

Comment: did you try it already? if not, nothing is wrong in trying

Comment: You bet I already tried a lot of ways, including all the above haha :P I mean it is not the end of the world if that is how it was meant to behave, but thought I would explore.

Comment: Hi, did you make any progress on this issue?

I too have this problem and don't want to use the package.

Comment: @ran3000 look at user10539074's answer, worked for me.

Answer (score 19):

As an option you can listen to window metrics change.

1. add `WidgetsBindingObserver` interface to State class
2. override `didChangeMetrics` method
3. add/remove listener in `initState` and `dispose` methods

see full code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: Home())));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  final FocusNode inputFocusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: TextFormField(
        focusNode: inputFocusNode,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
        maxLines: null,
        minLines: 3,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void didChangeMetrics() {
    super.didChangeMetrics();
    final value = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.viewInsets.bottom;
    if (value == 0) {
      inputFocusNode.unfocus();
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    inputFocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Wrap your whole App with this widget.

```
Listener(
 onPointerDown: (_) {
   FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
   if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus &&
   currentFocus.focusedChild != null) {
   currentFocus.focusedChild.unfocus();
  }
 },
 child: //MyApp()
)
```

Whenever the user taps anywhere else it removes the focus and cursor too.

Comment: do you know why it needs to be the parent of the whole app? I tried putting it at a lower level in the tree and it doesn't work

Comment: Surprisingly this "Listener" widget did what "GestureDetector" couldn't achieve. This should be marked as the answer. Thanks man.

Answer (score 5):

I am posting this as an answer as I cannot still comment because of my repo.
For me @user10539074's solution was not working as it was not letting the text field focus only (the keyboard was instantly getting closed as soon as it tried to open). So I added this extra line and it worked for me.

```
if (MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0)
{
     if (value == 0) {
          inputFocusNode.unfocus();
        }
}
```

What this check basically does is it runs that code only if the keyboard is already opened.

Answer (score 2):

You can check is visible keyboard or not and when it is not visible you can invoke `unfocus()` method. For example, to track the keyboard you can use this library [keyboard_visibility](https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_visibility). Example code:

```
FocusNode myFocusNode = FocusNode();

KeyboardVisibilityNotification().addNewListener(
    onChange: (bool visible) {
        if (!visible) {
            myFocusNode.unfocus()
        }
    },
);
```

Comment: It's too old and doesn't support Null Safety. Better to use [flutter_keyboard_visibility](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_visibility)